# Display build error in build status page (Jenkins)

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a freestyle jenkins project which basically just invokes a linux script which writes a long logfile.

If the script fails, then the last line of the logfile will be a human readable description, but I can't add any more build steps to parse it since it's already failed at this point.

Is there an easy way to basically do `msg=$(tail -n1 logfile.log)` and then display that `$msg` as a build description in the build status page?

It would make it much easier than having to click on the console output for each build and scroll to the bottom.

I have tried the `Customized Build Message` plugin which seems like it kind of works, except I can't export the logfile to access from an ENV variable. I also looked at the Console Log Parser, but it doesn't support just getting the last line.

Comment: [Build Failure Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer/) ?

Comment: Doesn't allow for tail -n or just N line grepping

Comment: Not tail -n,  but you can use a regular expression ( `^ERROR .*` ) and it supports multi-line,  or get more granular classification if you choose.

Comment: The log file can't be matched in that way. The only requirement is that the last line is the display line.